# how to send my file path to input of API File

Tags: firebase, api, google-text-to-speech

I am using 2 sources of audio file. The user can either write a text to speech or select a prerecorded audio file:

- text-to-speech (Google API)
- API File selection

Each one has its own form :

```
<!-- TEXT TO SPEECH -->
<form id="textToSpeechForm" class="col-md-6" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="textToUpload">Consigne audio :</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="textToUpload" name="textToUpload" row="3"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Enregistrer" name="submit">
  </div>
</form>

<!-- AUDIO FILE SELECTION -->
<form id="audioUpload" class="col-md-6" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> Sélectionner un fichier .mp3:
  <div class="form-row">
    <input type="file" class="btn btn-light" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Valider">
  </div>
</form>
```

These two forms are necessary to create a file in a local folder. 
I get the file path and I want to upload the file to Firebase using this method https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files.
But the tutorial explain how to send a file, but I only have the file path. 
How can I get the file with the file path without using API File input form?

Comment: Hello Amelie and welcome to Stack Overflow! Why do you need to save the file on your server? Note that with the Firebase JavaScript SDK you could directly upload your file from your HTML page to Cloud Storage (exactly as you have indicated with the link to the Firebase doc).

Comment: Hi Renaud, thanks. Well, when I use the text-to-speech API, I do it with PHP
`file_put_contents($filePath, $audioContent);
 echo $filePath;`
I wish I could put my $audioContent, which is supposed to be a binary, in a Blob URL, then get my Blob in my JS file

Comment: If I may, the exact flow of your solution is not clear to me, I probably missunderstand something :-). You should clarify, in your question why you want to use the Cloud Storage upoad files methods. Do you want to store this file on Cloud Storage? Or just having it on your own server is enough.

Comment: Renaud, thanks, I rewrite my question, hope it is more clear like this.

Comment: Ok thanks! When you say "I get the file path and I want to upload the file to Firebase using this method https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files." Where is the file? On your server (since it has been uploaded from your form)?. So you want to upload to Cloud Storage the file that is stored on your server, from your web application? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes exactly, I store it on my server in a sudfolder /admin/uploads

Comment: Hello. Why do you put it on your server? Is that mandatory?

Comment: No not mandatory but preferred. I thought that I could also use Blob, but didn't manage to put $audioContent in a blob